# Uri.fromParts gets me a %2F on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, uri

I use this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.fromParts("http", "//google.com/", "")); //fromParts is ok b/c the scheme is different
startActivity(i);
```

But on the browser on the Android Emulator I get this address:

> **http:%2F%2Fgoogle.com**

Why is that? and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java), `Uri.fromParts()` builds an `OpaqueUri` and `OpaqueUri.toString()` URL-encodes the scheme-specific part, changing `/` to `%2F`.

This is a [documented feature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromParts%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Encodes the ssp which means this method cannot be used to create hierarchical URIs.

To get the hierarchical Uri you want, use

```
Uri.parse("http://google.com/")
```

or use [`Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html).